# Exception during cache and session cleaning

Tags: exception, magento-connect-manager, ce-1.9.3.1

Every time, I install an extension through **Magento Connect Manager** I get the following error:

Exception during cache and session cleaning

I tried running **Magento Cleanup file and then try** again.

also tried `downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Helper/File/Gz.php` in your Magento directory and replace

```
$this->_fileHandler = @gzopen64($this->_filePath, $mode);
```

Still having issue; my Php Version is 5.5 if that helps and my host is Site Ground. I am lost why I am getting this error. Nothing in the logs either.

#### EDIT

Here is a screenshot of this error; I tried other extensions same thing

[image]

Comment: It was fine in version 1.8.1; is it a bug in 1.9.3.1?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

All you have to do is go to **downloader/Maged/Connect.php**, find

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.JSONeval(true) || {};
```

replace it with:

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || JSON.parse(transport.responseText) || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename var folder on root of magento directory, as Magento is saving its cache & session information there for case of if you've set file based. You could use C-Panel & shell both for this.

for shell access, mostly web applications reside in

/var/www/magento/var

or

/var/www/html/magento/var

cd /var/www/html/magento

sudo mv var var11jan17

Comment: What will renaming var folder do?

Comment: Magento, in this folder are the cache and session folder. In other words we are deleting the cache and session.

Comment: I deleted cache and sessions. I am thinking it has to do with permissions. Magento Connect tries to delete this after you install; remove; reinstall correct? Is this why I am getting this error Exception during cache and session cleaning? Permissions on Var folder is set to 755 since I have SuExec and I cant go with 777 could this be the issue

Comment: yeah var, media should be 777

Comment: You need to find out all correct permission mentioned in [magento1 site](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html) and also get the last release for magento1 which is [1.9.2.4](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?_ga=1.75845269.1460767463.1484168147#download1933) it does contains all the security patches and surprise for magento1

Comment: I am using 1.9.3.1 which was provided for me with my host; so it should be 1.9.2.4?